# How to avoid the "self" parameter in C?

Tags: c, oop

I was just playing arround with C. Here is some kind of "class" i made:

```
typedef struct test{
    int x;
    int y;
    int(*mul)(test *);

} mult;

int testMul(test *t){
    return t->x * t->y;
}

mult newTest(int x_in, int y_in){
    mult tmp;
    tmp.x = x_in;
    tmp.y = y_in;
    tmp.mul = &testMul;
    return tmp;
}
```

If I want to use the `mul()` "method", I do it like this:

```
mult a = newTest(2,6);
a.mul(&a); //12
```

Is there some clever way to avoid the `&a` param while still having access the struct-Params inside the `mul()` function?

Comment: You might make a macro to help you.

Comment: No, there's nothing that you *should do* in your code that can achieve this. Also, if you don't expect the function to be replaced/customized, you should simply make it an external function that takes your type as a parameter rather than attempting to duplicate the syntax of OOP languages (or just use C++). In C, though, the normal way is to write test_multiply(&a) instead of a.multiply() where "test" is the name of the "class".

Comment: `int testMul(test *t){` The typedeffed name is `mult`, not `test`. (are you using a C++ compiler, by any chance?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no *clean way* to do this, but you can`t avoid passing the reference to the function because functions are **stateless**.

But you could make it like this to make it look nicer:

(This goes implementation):

```c
struct test {
    int x;
    int y;
};

test_t _test_create(int const x, int const y)
{
    test_t t = malloc(sizeof(* t));
    if (!t) return NULL;

    t->x = x;
    t->y = y;
    return t;
}

int _test_mul(test_t t)
{
    return t->x * t->y;
}
```

Use a global variable holding the function pointers:

(This goes global):

```c
typedef struct test *test_t;

struct {
    test_t (*create)(int const x, int const y);
    int (*mul)(test_t t);
} test = { // <- also implementation (you don`t want to expose private function names)
    .create = _test_create,
    .mul    = _test_mul
};
```

Then you would call it just like this:

```c
test_t a = test.create(2, 6);

test.mul(a);
```

This has the advantage that you always see to what `a` is referenced to. But it also consumes more memory because of the `test` pointer table.

Other way around this (warning macro ahead):

```c
#define test(obj, method, args...)    \
   (obj)->method(args)

test_t a = newTest(2, 6);
test(a, mul);
```

But this only works with pointers. And you need to be **very** careful.

Comment: I like your solution but would you recomend it for use or would you just pass the reference?

Comment: I would make the type *opaque* to the client and just use/pass the reference. (But without the user knowing it). On allocating, I would use the reference to the reference (e.g. test.create(&test, 2, 6) (only you need return values)). Otherwise `test_t test = test.create(2, 6);`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define a helper function (named after the class name `mult` and the method name `mul`):

```
int mult_mul(mult *x) { return x->mul(x); }
```

Then you would:

```
mult a = newTest(2,6);
mult_mul(&a));
```

This provides the polymorphic behaviour without having to repeat the object name `a`. Of course for other methods you can add additional arguments to the `mult_xxx()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I normally go for a macro, for instance

```
#define MUL(a) (a).mul(&(a))
```

Comment: While this works, it is a hack and something I strongly recommend against doing in any real code.

Comment: But if I use it like this, theres not reason to add my function to the struct a all, isn't it? What do I do if I have two struct-types with different mul functions? (For example float and int)

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I completely failed to see what's hackish about this. I often find myself naturally needing to attach different functions to different instances of a certain `struct`. And with this sort of macro, every instance is a stand-alone and I only need to change its initialization line to change the function attached to it.

Comment: @Dounut: There was no reason to attach the function in the first place.

Comment: @downhillFromHere it's hackish in that macros completely replace the underlying code and have no notion of scoping or type safety. Macros are reasonable to use under certain limited circumstances, but this is not one of them.